# Package Manager Console can't find packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, package-managers

I'm trying to

```
Install-Package NHibernate
```

but I'm getting "Package ... could not be found". If I open the PCM-options, the list of available sources is filled, but the green OK-symbol isn't there.

Can I use an alternative source different to the MS-Links-ID 206669 which is the default source in VS?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of nuget installed?

Comment: Can you see the packages in your browser if you go to the package source directly?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem last night.  The two LinkID values I had were:

206669 and 19913

Meaning that the URL I pass into the Settings dialog were:

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=19913

The 19913 did not yield anything in the list of packages available.  I think this number came when I installed the package a few weeks (months?) ago and gave up the first time.

The 206669 seemed to work.  I could see the expected packages, but I could only install some packages, not all.  For example, I could get Castle, but not Log4net.  I could get AutoMapper, but not RestSharp.  The ones that failed simply said "operation timeout".

I'm glad that I'm not the only one to see these issues - I did not see anything about this in the FAQs or documentation.

It seems that the LinkID and that URL are a weakness in the framework.  I would like to see more discussion about that these values mean, and why there seem to be now at least 3 different values to use.  How about a more clear link like www.nuget.com?
And how about a message showing more clearly why an operation times out on one package but not another.

NuGet has great promise, and many people swear by it.  I want to get on board, but hiccups like this can really stop people from adopting it.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll test that out tomorrow. I guess nuget will not work properly behind proxy-servers because thats the point at the place where it wont work for me. I'll test that out.

Comment: No effect at my site. the 19913 seems to be ignored completely and it stays complaining about "{url} is either invalid..."